# Run dll using powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

This is my .net code

```
namespace MyMathLib
{
    public class Methods
    {
        public Methods()
        {
        }
        public static int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int Product(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to load my dll using powershell

```
$AssemblyPath = "D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyMathLib.dll"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($AssemblyPath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
[MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)
```

It gives below error . dll location is ok.. can anyone please help

```
Unable to find type [MyMathLib.Methods].
At line:4 char:1
+ [MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MyMathLib.Methods:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

how to resolve this?`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `Assembly.Load()` instead of `Add-Type -Path $AssemblyPath`?

Comment: My objective to run my dll using powershell anyway.. but still if i use Add -type like below

Add-Type -Path "D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyMathLib.dll" 
[MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)

It gives error

Comment: You should add your Add-Type code & details of the error you encounter using it as that solution will likely be the best.

Comment: And which version of Powershell is that that you use? I would think that loading a .NET 6 assembly requires a .NET Core version of Powershell (and might not work with the older, Windows only, .NET framework based version of Powershell).

Comment: .NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000
Assembly version: 1.0.0.0
                                                                                                                      
Assembly is compatible with the version of .NET that PowerShell is running on.

I use .net framework 6.0 in visual studio 2022

Comment: Add-Type -Path "D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyMathLib.dll" 
[MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path "D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyMa ...

Unable to find type [MyMathLib.Methods].
At line:2 char:1
[MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)

 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MyMathLib.Methods:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Your path `D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net6.0` suggests you are building a .NET 6 (.NET Core) dll, I doubt there is any .NET framework 6, Windows .NET framework highest is 4.8.

Comment: D:\Visual Studio code\EvenOdd\bin\Debug\net6.0>dotnet --version
7.0.100..

can't identify what i'm doing wrong

Comment: In your Powershell, if you enter `$PSVersionTable`, what does it show for `PSEdition`?

Comment: PSVersion      5.1.19041.2364                                                                                                                                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions      {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop

Comment: That is the .NET framework based Powershell so write a .NET framework library/DLL to use it with that version/edition of Powershell. Your current library would work if you ran (might first need to install it) Powershell 7 based on .NET Core.

Comment: Try :  MyMathLib.Methods.Sum(10, 2)

Comment: Did the comments or the answer help you to get your library to run in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

To write a .NET library that is compatible with both the Desktop/Windows .NET framework edition of Powershell as well as with the .NET Core edition make sure you target .NET standard 2.0 for the library/DLL (and not .NET 6).

So in your VS project use e.g.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

and not `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`. For .NET 6.0 use/install Powershell Core (current release is Powershell 7).

Comment: Hi Martin, When I add net standard 2.0 this in my existing .csproj  it gives below error


1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\Visual Studio code\MyMathLib\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netstandard2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
Build failed.

Comment: I have created one new class project Targeting .net standard 2.1 .... When I execute on powershell it gives below error  Unable to find type [MyMathLib1.Methods].

Comment: .NET standard 2.1 is not compatible with the .NET framework

Comment: I would suggest to create a new library project with target framework .NET Standard 2.0, that way you should get a dll loadable from the .NET framework/desktop/Windows Powershell.

Comment: when I create new library project with 2.0 dependencies and packages aren't  loading.. is there any way to manually load dependencies?